# How I can get precision, recall and F-measure of positive and negative predictions from a nltk classifier?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

I am trying to get precision, recall and F-measure of positive and negative predictions for sentiment analysis. 
I used python 3.6 as follow:

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize 
# Trainng data    
train = [('I love this sandwich.', 'pos'),
         ('This is an amazing place!', 'pos'),
         ('I feel very good about these beers.', 'pos'),
         ('This is my best work.', 'pos'),
         ("What an awesome view", 'pos'),
         ('I do not like this restaurant', 'neg'),
         ('I am tired of this stuff.', 'neg'),
         ("I can't deal with this", 'neg'),
         ('He is my sworn enemy!', 'neg'),
         ('My boss is horrible.', 'neg') ]

# Test data   
test = [('The beer was good.', 'pos'),
        ('I do not enjoy my job', 'neg'),
        ("I ain't feeling dandy today.", 'neg'),
        ("I feel amazing!", 'pos'),
        ('Gary is a friend of mine.', 'pos'),
        ("I can't believe I'm doing this.", 'neg') ]


# Tokenize Training words
Training_words = set(word.lower() for passage in train for word in word_tokenize(passage[0]))

# Training feature sets
training_set = [({word: (word in word_tokenize(x[0])) for word in Training_words}, x[1]) for x in train]

# Tokenize Test words
Test_words = set(word.lower() for passage in test for word in word_tokenize(passage[0]))

# Test feature sets
test_set= [({word: (word in word_tokenize(x[0])) for word in Test_words}, x[1]) for x in test]

# Naive Bayes classifier
classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(training_set)

# Informative Features
classifier.show_most_informative_features()

# print the accuracy 
print("accuracy %",(nltk.classify.accuracy(classifier, test_set))*100)
```

The above code display the Informative Features and the accuracy of the Naive Bayes classifier.
I tried the code below to get its precision , recall and F-measure of  positive and negative predictions.

```
from nltk.metrics.scores import (precision, recall)
import collections
import nltk.metrics

refsets = collections.defaultdict(set)
testsets = collections.defaultdict(set)
for i, (feats, label) in enumerate(test_set):
    refsets[label].add(i)
    observed = classifier.classify(feats)
    testsets[observed].add(i)


print ('NB pos precision %', nltk.metrics.precision(refsets['pos'], testsets['pos'])*100)
print ('NB pos recall %', nltk.metrics.recall(refsets['pos'], testsets['pos'])*100)
print ('NB pos F-measure %', nltk.metrics.f_measure(refsets['pos'], testsets['pos'])*100)
print ('NB neg precision %', nltk.metrics.precision(refsets['neg'], testsets['neg'])*100)
print ('NB neg recall %', nltk.metrics.recall(refsets['neg'], testsets['neg'])*100)
print ('NB neg F-measure %', nltk.metrics.f_measure(refsets['neg'], testsets['neg'])*100)
```

I need your hep please..

Comment: Also if I used more than one classifier such as SVM and KNN
how I can get precision , recall and F-measure of each classifier?